# How to force compiler to mangle C names to C++ names

Tags: c++, c, windows, symbols, name-mangling

I have .obj with function that has everything it needs to be linked as C++ member function. Problem is, it's in C and thus the class using it expects something uglier than it's normal name. So I figure this can be done in only 2 ways: either mangle the name of the C function and/or add additional symbol to the symbol table that would have the mangled name anyway, but I could still use it's original name too.. so mangle the name basically. Any ideas how to do this or have some completely other way of solving this? Please share but do consider usefulness of saying extern "C" in this particular case :)) thx

Comment: A C function *that has everything it needs to be linked as C++ member function* ?? Really, including the *this* pointer? How can that be? AFAIK C doesn't know about *this*.

Comment: Because I specified it as first parameter..

Comment: you are not asking the real question. there's got a be a reason to write c++ as c. normally you do the opposite, write c++ class and wrap it with c interface, when `this` added as `void*` as the first argument in each method .

Comment: You could try mangling the names manually and putting the mangled names in the C code, but I am not sure why you don't just use a c++ compiler?

Answer (score 7):

Your (C-based) object file has a symbol and you cannot redefine that symbol to have a different name -- that would be a task for the compiler generating that object file. The C compiler doesn't know about C++ and it cannot be made to emit a symbol with C++ linkage and name mangling. So the only way to use that symbol (your C function) is to call it by the symbol it is know for.

You can, of course, use that function to *implement* a C++ (member) function (the additional level of indirection is optimised away **if** the call is `inline`) as in

```
extern "C" { int my_C_func(void*, int); }  // could be in an included header

struct A {
  // implement the followind member using the C function
  int operator()(int i) { return my_C_func(this,i); }
};
```

---

If the C++ class is already declared and its declaration cannot be touched, then you can still implement the member function in the same way in a separate source file. However, this cannot be `inline` and hence comes at the cost of an additional function call:

```
in file.cpp:

extern "C" { int my_C_func(void*, int); }  // could be in an included header
int A::operator()(int i) { return my_C_func(this,i); }
```

---

From your reply to me comment, I conclude that you actually have control of the implementation of the C function. So, why do you need to implement this in C? Why can't you simply implement it in C++? Then you will get the correct linkage and name mangling and you can directly implement the desired member function.